# How to limit a number of messages recieved by a device on Azure IoTHUB

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, throttling

I need to limit a device to 1 message every 60 seconds and I do not know how to do this. I can limit the entry in the DB but I am not sure how to prevent throttling on the IoTHub. I am concerned that a device might accidentally spam IoTHub if the wrong interval to send data is entered, like say maybe 0.006 milliseconds instead of 60000. I would like to block all messages from the same device, or kick the device, if it tries to send more than 1 message within some time threshold. I couldn't find any good documentation on this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The closest would be using Azure Stream Analytics and some windowing function to get the latest of first message in a 1 minute interval

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. I think Azure recommends creating a custom function to handle this but I wasn't sure if it already existed out of the box. It should!!

Comment: How does this go against a servless direction? The hub will throttle itself if a single device spams it. Once throttled, all devices will have issues sending data to the hub. This seems unfair for the other devices. To me, it seems this should be a setting that can be set for every device upon creation. I will create a custom function to handle this since it is not that simple though.

Comment: sorry ... it was a comment to another answer I provided.

Answer (score -1):

Curious to understand the use case, the message rate is always controlled at the device end and not the service as it is in control of the rate. Opening a connection and spamming the service is odd pattern. IoT Hub and any similar public service will always throttle to prevent abuse at the service level not device. Designing ingestion service that can hold 1 million concurrent connections with per device throttling is tall order at the price point.